# Unable to Connect to MongoDB from Elasticsearch's MongoDB Connector

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, database-connection, connector, mongo-connector

I'm trying to connect Elasticsearch(version 8.9.2) to MongoDB(Server Version 6.0.7) using the MongoDB connector provided by Elasticsearch on their [webpage](https://www.elastic.co/). I have a MongoDB instance that I can successfully connect to from various servers and networks using Studio 3T, but when I try to use the Elasticsearch connector, I encounter the following error:

```
Connector error

my_mongo_bd_intance_ip:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 64f5a87e74610cee14685304, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('my_mongo_bd_intance_ip', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('my_mongo_bd_intance_ip:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused')>]>
```

- MongoDB is running and accessible from multiple locations.
- I've confirmed that there are no issues with authentication since Studio 3T connects without any problems.
- Network connectivity has been verified as not being the issue.
- I've provided the correct host name, username, password, database name, and collection name in the Elasticsearch connector configuration.

What I am thinking is maybe I need to use ssh tunel to connect with the database maybe but no idea how to for [ElasticSearch Platform](https://www.elastic.co/).

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

screenshot:
[image]